# cannot read property 'map' of undefined when pass state and map it as props

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to pass state from App.js component to ShopsMap component which exist in Home.js and this is the code of passing

```
render() {
    const { shops, region } = this.state;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ShopsMap shops={shops} region={region} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

in Home.js I have this structure where I have ShopsMap and ShopsDetails components and I tried to navigate between these two components as shown in this code :

```
class ShopsMap extends Component {
  renderMarkers() {
    return this.props.shops.map((marker, i) => (
      <Marker key={i} title={marker.name} coordinate={marker.coords} >
      <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </Marker>
    ));
  }
  componentDidMount() { }

  render() {
    const region = this.props.region;
    return (
      <MapView
        region={region}
        showsUserLocation
        showsMyLocationButton
      >
        {this.renderMarkers()}
      </MapView>
    );
  }
}

class ShopsDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Map"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Map')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Map: {
      screen: ShopsMap,
    },
    Details: {
      screen: ShopsDetails,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Map',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

I get this error cannot read property 'map' of undefined
while when I have only ShopsMap in Home.js and export this class directly everything work fine but when change the structure to navigate between component I get this error

Comment: Did you add Map to your navigation stack?

Comment: yes see the code I have added the code of navigation too @Woj

Comment: you have already pushed your screen into navigation stack. so use this.props.navigation.goBack() to pop to map screen

Comment: where do you mean to use this.props.navigation.goBack() ? @ Selva Murugan

Comment: this.props.navigation.navigate('Map')

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) in order to get how to pass parameters to screens

Comment: the way you talk about is how to pass parameters between 2 components like ShopsMap and ShopsDetails in my code right? but what I'm asked about is how to pass from App.js to Home.js where the ShopsMap exist, do you understand what I mean? @Andrei Vedovato

Comment: Ok, got two ideas:

1. In Home class, try to return <AppContainer {...this.props} />;

2. In parent component, try to pass the props as follows:
<ShopsMap shops={this.state.shops} region={this.state.region} />

Comment: I already use the second idea and pass from parent App.js like this: <ShopsMap shops={this.state.shops} region={this.state.region} /> then in Home.js particulary in ShopsMap class I tried to get the props that I pass but get the error of cannot read property 'map' of undefined so any suggestion please @Andrei Vedovato

Comment: Looks like the component which receive the props from Parent aren't passing them down to the children you need so probably the first idea would work. Can you please confirm?

Comment: I tried the first one too but get the same result I would like to accept you answer if you help me to make it work :( if I use the first idea then what should I pass from the parent App.js to Home.js ? @Andrei Vedovato

Comment: So maybe i'll be able to better help if you provide a code repository so i can reproduce and test it :)

Comment: how to provide code repository? like upload it in google drive?

Comment: Ideally Github so i can clone it and install dependencies.Please note that the node_modules folder should not be in the package so i'll install them by myself

Comment: Ok, gonna respond you in a few hours

Comment: waiting you @Andrei Vedovato

Answer (score 0):

Got two ideas:

1- In Home class, try to:

`return <AppContainer {...this.props} />`

---

2 - In parent component, try to pass the props as follows:

`<ShopsMap shops={this.state.shops} region={this.state.region} />`